# Minipage in Mdframed-Environment

Tags: minipage, mdframed

The last equations in these two mini pages in a mdframed-environment have a weird indent and the spacing for the text underneath them is also strange. How can one fix this?

```
\documentclass[
10pt, % Main document font size
a4paper, % Paper type, use 'letterpaper' for US Letter paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{MyFrame}{%
linecolor=orange,
outerlinewidth=2pt,
roundcorner=20pt,
innertopmargin=\baselineskip,
innerbottommargin=\baselineskip,
innerrightmargin=20pt,
innerleftmargin=20pt,
backgroundcolor=gray!20!white}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[style=MyFrame]
\begin{center}
{\textbf{Wiederholung}: Quadratische Erg{\"a}nzung} 
\end{center}%
\bigskip
\noindent Manchmal kommt die Kreisgleichung in ausmultiplizierter Form    
vor, zum Beispiel $x_{1}^2 + 8x_{1} + x_{2}^2 + 6x_{2} = 0$. In diesem 
Fall kann man die Gleichung durch \textbf{quadratische Erg{\"a}nzung} 
auf die Koordinatengleichung zur{\"u}ckf{\"u}hren, in dem man die 
Gleichung in zwei Gleichungen aufteilt und beide auf eine binomische 
Formel zur{\"u}ckf{\"u}hrt:

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{equation*}
(x_{1}+a)^2 \Leftrightarrow x_{1}^2 + 8x_{1} = 0 \quad |+16
\end{equation*}%
\begin{equation*}
(x_{1}+a)^2 \Leftrightarrow x_{1}^2 + 8x_{1} + 16 = 16 \quad
\end{equation*}%
\begin{equation*}
(x_{1}+a)^2 \Leftrightarrow (x_{1} + 4)^2 = 16 \quad
\end{equation*}%
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{equation*}
(x_{2}+b)^2 \Leftrightarrow x_{2}^2 + 6x_{2} = 0 \quad |+9
\end{equation*}%
\begin{equation*}
(x_{2}+b)^2 \Leftrightarrow x_{2}^2 + 6x_{2} + 9 = 9
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
(x_{2}+b)^2 \Leftrightarrow (x_{2} + 3)^2 = 9
\end{equation*}
\end{minipage}%
\newline
\smallskip
Durch Gleichsetzen beider Gleichungen erh{\"a}lt man folgende    Gleichung:
\begin{equation*}
(x_{1} + 4)^2 + (x_{2} + 3)^2 = 0 + 16 + 9
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
(x_{1} + 4)^2 + (x_{2} + 3)^2 = 25
\end{equation*}
Dies ist die Koordinatenform, aus der  sich nun der Mittelpunkt    
$M(-4|-3)$ und der Radius $r = 5$ ablesen lassen. 
\end{mdframed}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note how the third equations are shifted to the left and the line spacing with the paragraph below is not proper. Neither `\newline` nor `\smallskip` has an effect on it though.

Sorry, the text is in German but it shouldn't matter.

**The math is totally broken, as the comments pointed out. I fixed it in the MWE (just for it to look halfway serious) but haven't updated the picture.**

Comment: Unrelated comment: the radius isn't `$r=29$` but `$r=\sqrt{26}$` and *M* is (-1|-5).

Comment: Oh dear, what was I doing... thanks ;) I'm writing just a few demo things to get the lay-out correct, but this is a pretty huge mistake 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `minipage`s, you should never use a flock of equations. Use one of the `align*` or `alignat*` environments:

```
    \documentclass[
    10pt, % Main document font size
    a4paper, % Paper type, use 'letterpaper' for US Letter paper
    ]{scrartcl}

    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

    \mdfdefinestyle{MyFrame}{%
    linecolor=orange,
    outerlinewidth=2pt,
    roundcorner=20pt,
    innertopmargin=\baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin=\baselineskip,
    innerrightmargin=20pt,
    innerleftmargin=20pt,
    backgroundcolor=gray!20!white}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{mdframed}[style=MyFrame]
    \begin{center}
    {\textbf{Heading}: This is a title!}
    \end{center}%
    \bigskip
    \lipsum[1]
    Text text text text text
    \begin{align*}
     &
    \begin{gathered}
    (x_{1}+a)^2 \Leftrightarrow x_{1}^2 + 2x_{1} = 0 \quad |+4\\
    (x_{1}+a)^2 \Leftrightarrow x_{1}^2 + 2x_{1} + 4 = 4 \quad\\
    (x_{1}+a)^2 \Leftrightarrow (x_{1} + 2)^2 = 4 \quad
    \end{gathered}%
     & &
    \begin{gathered}
    (x_{2}+b)^2 \Leftrightarrow x_{2}^2 + 10x_{2} = 0 \quad |+25\\
    (x_{2}+b)^2 \Leftrightarrow x_{2}^2 + 10x_{2} + 25 = 25\\
    (x_{2}+b)^2 \Leftrightarrow (x_{2} + 5)^2 = 25
    \end{gathered}
    \end{align*}%
    \lipsum[2]
    Text text text text text
    \begin{alignat*}{2}
     (x_{1}+a)^2 & \Leftrightarrow x_{1}^2 + 2x_{1} = 0 \quad |+4 &\qquad (x_{2}+b)^2 &\Leftrightarrow x_{2}^2 + 10x_{2} = 0 \quad |+25\\
    (x_{1}+a)^2 & \Leftrightarrow x_{1}^2 + 2x_{1} + 4 = 4 \quad & (x_{2}+b)^2 & \Leftrightarrow x_{2}^2 + 10x_{2} + 25 = 25\\
    (x_{1}+a)^2 & \Leftrightarrow (x_{1} + 2)^2 = 4 \quad & (x_{2}+b)^2 & \Leftrightarrow (x_{2} + 5)^2 = 25
    \end{alignat*}%
    \end{mdframed}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't know the feature `gathered` before!

Comment: Every `amsmath` environment has a ‘relative’ version, for nested environments (`aligned`, `alignedat`, `gathered`, `multlined` — the latter requires `mathtools`.